# How to change order / presentation when echo?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the way a playlist looks when I fetch it form the database.
Right now when I echo out the playlist `( echo $row['lista']; )` it will look like this:

`1.2.3.`    and so on...

I wanna make it look like this:

```
1.    
2.    
3.    
...
```

Is this possible?

I've  tried all your suggestions, it's not working. Does it have something to do with the text in the table? It just looks like this:

1. Den självslagne 2. En sångarsaga 3. Infruset 4. I ungdomen 5. Snigelns visa 6. Strövtåg i hembygden 7. Men 8. En ung mor 9. Titania 10. Gråbergssång

Comment: Yes this is possible but usually done via HTML/CSS

Comment: Add '<br/>' may be. This will give the next out put on next line. Or `<ol></ol>`

Comment: `echo $row['lista'].'<br/>'`?

Comment: `echo $row['lista']."<br /><br />";`

Answer (score 1):

You need a line break here.

You are not adding any line break so, the data is getting printed side by side.

All you need is:

```
echo $row['lista'] . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<br />' . $row['lista'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
echo "{$row['lista']}\n\n";
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. When you run first time value printed in first line and then cursor move to next line and print next value and then cursor move next line so on.

```
echo $row['lista']."<br/>";
```

it all about the html and css, how you are preparing you content to display.

Answer (score 0):

A line break should have printed the values one below the other.

If this does not help I guess I would like to have a look at the code especially the loop which has $row['lista'].

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['lista']; }

Comment: If this is the only line that is there in your while loop the line break suggestions should have helped. So let us take a look at the query which is stored in $result and the values in your database too.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM musik");

Comment: there's more lines in the code, but just more echo like the one I already posted

Comment: 'lista' from the table has the type TEXT

Comment: If the lista from the table has the type TEXT. Does it have all the values in one row itself in the table?

Comment: nope.. if I look in phpMyAdmin it looks like I want it to

Comment: Which means that these values viz. 1. Den självslagne 2. En sångarsaga 3. Infruset 4. I ungdomen 5. Snigelns visa 6. Strövtåg i hembygden 7. Men 8. En ung mor 9. Titania 10. Gråbergssång are on different rows.

Comment: Hm I see, I think I understand, i'll try this again.